# I create Item by using Directus SDK I got error Access to fetch from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, directus

```js
const handleSubmit = async(e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await directusClient.request(
      createItem('Subscripber', {
        email: Email,
        phone_number: Phonenum
      })
    )
    
    console.log('success')
  }
```

I expecting one solution that can help.

Comment: Please add more debugging details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.